# Getting Meteor private folder path in Meteor Deploy Environment

Tags: deployment, meteor, path

I need to get the path of the file inside the private folder.
On my local machine I was able to get it by using the path `"../../../../../"`, however, when I deployed to meteor server using `meteor deploy`, it doesn't work anymore. Also I tried to log the current directory using `process.cwd()` and got the following, which is different from the structure I got on my local machine:

```
/meteor/containers/3906c248-566e-61b7-4637-6fb724a33c16/bundle/programs/server
```

The directory logged from my local machine gives:

```
/Users/machineName/Documents/projectName/.meteor/local/build/programs/server
```

Note: I am using this path to setup https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `assets/app/` as the relative path. While this may not make sense on the first look Meteor re-arranges your `/private` directory to map to `assets/app` from the `/programs/server` directory. This is both in development and production.

Basically assume that `private/` maps to `assets/app/`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Where would I find information about this? Tried to look in the documentation and couldn't find it.

Comment: @doog There's no docs on this i'm afraid. If you follow your `.meteor/local/build/programs/server` path it will perhaps be clearer. This directory is really where the app runs from

Comment: You are god
Lol, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Call Assets.absoluteFilePath(assetPath) on one of the assets in the private folder, then chop of the name of the asset file from the string you get back, e.g., assuming you have a file called test.txt in the private folder:

```
var aFile = 'test.txt';// test.txt is in private folder
var aFilePath = Assets.absoluteFilePath(aFile);
var aFolder =  aFilePath.substr(0, aFilePath.length - aFile.length);
console.log(aFolder);
```

https://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html#Assets-absoluteFilePath