# How to read a file and output to client in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

In meteor is it possible to click on a button on the client and then have that button output a files contents from the server?

The reason for this is based around documentation. I'd like to create a button that can copy and paste the html from a template file.

On the server side I'd need to read the file and then somehow pass that to the client to output. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below should do the job:

### Server side:

```
Meteor.methods({
  loadFile:function(path){
          var fs = Npm.require('fs');
          return fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');

  }
})
```

### Client side:

```
Template.NAME.created = function(){
   this.file = new ReactiveVar("");
}

Template.NAME.helpers({
   file:function(){
       return Template.instance().file.get()
   }
})

Template.NAME.events({
   'click button':function(e,t){
       Meteor.call('loadFile','public/file.html', function(err, result)          {
         if(!err){
            t.file.set(result)
         }else{
            console.error('Error', err)
         }
       })
    }   
})
```

Comment: I'm getting a file read error, any tips?

` Exception while invoking method 'getFile' Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'public/file.html'`

Comment: Fixed it by attaching it to a base     var base = process.env.PWD;

Comment: so this actually breaks on production because demetorizer / building the project creates a different app structure. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry to hear. I don't use demeteorizer, so it is working for my production deployments. Pls check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743806/getting-meteor-private-folder-path-in-meteor-deploy-environment

Comment: so should this work if you replace all npm file with Assets.getFile?